# Pattern match on BTreeSet

Tags: rust, set

I want to be able to do something like

```rs
let set = BTreeSet::<(usize, &str)>::from([(2, "hey"), (1, "first"), (1, "second"), (3, "hello")]);
let modified: BTreeSet<(usize, &str)> = match set {
  [init @ .., (n, text)] => init + (n, "largest"),
  _ => todo!()
};
assert_eq!(modified, BTreeSet::<(usize, &str)>::from([(2, "hey"), (1, "first"), (1, "second"), (3, "largest")]));
```

I've tried converting the set to a slice representation so it can be matched on

```rs
match set.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice() {
  [init @ .., (n, text)] => BTreeSet::from_iter([[(n, "largest")], init].concat()),
  _ => todo!()
}
```

But this causes the error

```
7 |   [init @ .., (n, text)] => BTreeSet::from_iter([[(n, "largest")], init].concat()),
  |                                                                    ^^^^ expected array of 1 element, found `&[&(usize, &str)]`
```

There's probably a more sensible solution anyway, I've not yet wrapped my head around borrowing etc. in Rust.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply using [`pop_first` or `pop_last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.pop_first) on a `.clone()`?

Comment: @cafce25 yeah, my edit is more similar to the actual problem i'm trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some dissonance because your `[(n, "largest")]` is an array of 1 tuple, while `init` is a slice of references to tuples. That is what the compiler means with the error (it even adds a note detailing the found types):

```
... expected array of 1 element, found `&[&(usize, &str)]`
  = note:  expected array `[(&usize, &str); 1]`
          found reference `&[&(usize, &str)]`
```

There is also the issue of `n` being a `&usize` instead of a `usize` but that is easily solved by just writing `*n` instead.

The thing is that `concat()` creates a `Vec<>` under the hood, so you are actually collecting all the values before adding them to the new `BTreeMap`. You can do that manually and it is easier to write and read:

```
        [init @ .., (n, text)] => {
            let mut v = vec![(*n, "largest")];
            v.extend(init.iter().copied());
            BTreeSet::from_iter(v.into_iter())
        }
```

Naturally, if you insist you can do it still in one line. It is tricky because `concat()` takes a slice as argument, and all the values need to have the same type such as *references to slices of references to tuples* (`&[&(usize, &str)]`):

```
[init @ .., (n, text)] => {
    BTreeSet::from_iter(
        [ [&(*n, "largest")].as_slice(), init ]
            .concat()
            .into_iter()
            .copied()
    )
```

But then, instead of using `slice::concat` it probably faster, and easier, to use `Iterator::chain` that does not collect the values into a `Vec`:

```
        [init @ .., (n, text)] => {
            BTreeSet::from_iter(
                std::iter::once((*n, "largest"))
                    .chain(init.iter().map(|x| **x))
            )
        }
```

You need to use the `map(|x| **x)` trick instead of `copied()` because init is actually a double reference (a reference to a slice of references). I think it worked in the previous one with `Vec::extend` because there is an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#impl-Extend%3C%26%27a%20T%3E-for-Vec%3CT%2C%20A%3E) of that function that does an additional `copy` if required.

Comment: Thank you for such a patient and thorough answer! What do you think about my idea of converting BTreeSet to a slice to pattern match on it? Does that expose glaring potential problems?

Comment: @minseong: Well, if your original container is big, then you may have performance issues, because you are copying the whole container into a `Vec` and then copying it again into a new `BTreeMap`. If the container is small, then performane would not matter. Anyway I would consider maybe cloning the `BTree` and using `pop_first()` or `pop_last()`, and then adding the `"largest"` value, as _cafce25_ suggested in the comment above. Maybe not as fancy as the `match` but easier to understand.

Comment: Why do you call `.copied()` on the iterator? What if the item type does not implement copied? i replaced `.copied` with `.collect()` and now my errors are like "expected `BTreeSet<(usize, Expression)>` found `BTreeSet<&&(usize, Expression)>`

Comment: Even `.map(|x| **x)` seems to not work if `Copy` is not implemented. Do you know what I can do in the case that `Copy` is not implemented?

Comment: @minseong: Ah, that is because you are now using `Expression` instead of `&str`. That makes your OP a bit misleading, because `&str` is `Copy` while `Expression` is not. I guess you can try `map(|x| x.clone())`. If that does not work you would need to rethink your design, because you cannot have the same object into two containers at the same time.